# How can I correctly use Mock in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I have a non - private and non - final repository classes which I wonna test. My simple test looks like: `

```
import com.trainig.spring.main.project.entity.User;
import com.trainig.spring.main.project.mapper.ForUnitTestUserRowMapper;
import com.trainig.spring.main.project.repository.user.UserRepository;
import com.trainig.spring.main.project.repository.user.UserRepositoryImpl;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import static com.trainig.spring.main.project.repository.user.UserRepositoryImpl.FIND_BY_NAME;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class UserRepositoryImplTest {

@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void initMocks(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void findByNameTest() {
    String userName = "Name";
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName(userName);
    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userRepository, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            FIND_BY_NAME,
            new ForUnitTestUserRowMapper(),
            userName))
            .thenReturn(user);
    assertEquals(user, userRepository.findByName(userName));
}
```

}

where I mocked an autowired bean jdbcTemplate.
But when I started the app, it fails with next exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes. If you're not
> sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
>
> Java               : 11 JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation JVM
> vendor version : 11.0.9+7-LTS JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM)
> 64-Bit Server VM JVM version        : 11.0.9+7-LTS JVM info
> : mixed mode OS name            : Windows 10 OS version         : 10.0
>
> Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot
> define class using reflection
>
> at
> com.training.spring.main.project.repository.user.UserRepositoryImplTest.initMocks(UserRepositoryImplTest.java:26)

What did I wrong? I did all like it's been written in the article.
[Spring unit test article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-testing)

Comment: There is nothing in `JdbcTemplate` class that would prevent Mockito from mocking it (no need for `mock-maker-inline` or other tricks). Make sure all your mockito related dependencies have the same version. If you're using Maven, run `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to tell Mockito to use the in-line mockmaker.**

Mockito can't mock final classes by default. It needs a different mockmaker (the class that creates the mocks) for that.

Create the following directory:
`src/test/resources/mockito-extensions`
with the following line:
`mock-maker-inline`

That should make the exception go away. See also [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final) Baeldung post.

However, I would strongly recommend to use `@DataJpaTest` for testing the repository layer. See also [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-datajpatest) Baeldung post.

Comment: Now I have gotten an other error : Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes

Comment: Hm, too bad. :/ I don't think mocking the `JdbcTemplate` class is the way to go. I recommend, if possible, going the `@DataJpaTest` route which will execute against an in-memory database. That way you can test if the queries in the template work rather than trying to stub those out.